# How to preserve case in jsoup parsing?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using jsoup to parse some HTML content. After parsing the HTML content, it changes the camel cased attributes to lowercase like 
`<svg viewBox='XXXX'>` to `<svg viewbox='XXXX'>`.

Can someone suggest me how i can preserve the case while parsing html content using jsoup 1.8.1?

Answer (score 14):

I just released [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) [1.10.1](https://jsoup.org/news/release-1.10.1) which includes support for preserving tag and/or attribute case. You can control it with [ParseSettings](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/ParseSettings.html). By default the HTML parser will continue to lower case normalize tags and attributes, and the XML parser will preserve them. You can specify these settings when you create the parser.

To use the **XML parser** (which preserves case by default):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml, baseUrl, Parser.xmlParser());
```

To use the **HTML parser** and set it to preserve-case:

```
Parser parser = Parser.htmlParser();
parser.settings(new ParseSettings(true, true)); // tag, attribute preserve case
Document doc = parser.parseInput(html, baseUrl);
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be quite difficult to preserve attribute's name character case when parsing document. The line responsible for converting all attributes names to lowercase is [TokeniserState.java#649](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/jsoup-1.8.2/src/main/java/org/jsoup/parser/TokeniserState.java#L649) as for JSoup 1.8.2, and there's no space to insert user's custom code.

The most you can do is to download sources, modify the line and build your own copy of library.

You should also consider if it would not introduce some strange behaviour if you did't convert attributes' names to lowercase. Maybe some problems with `Document.getElementByAttribute` or even other dependant functions?