# Html parser to replace hyperlinks in html document by preserving original html tags and line breaks

Tags: java, html-parsing

I am using Jsoup html parser for replacing hyperlinks in a html document. I want actual case, elements and line breaks to be as is even after updating the html document. But, Jsoup is updating the case to lowercase, updating few elements and also removing the line breaks. I have tried with ParseSettings also. But with parse settings, `doc.select("a[href]")` is not returning the elements. Below is the code I am using.

Can someone help me with the right html parser using java to replace hyperlinks by retaining the html document as is?

```
File input = new File(fileEntry.getPath());
Parser parser = Parser.htmlParser();
parser.settings(new ParseSettings(true, true)); 
Document doc = parser.parseInput(input.toString(), "UTF-8");
Elements anchorLinks = doc.select("a[href]");
```

Comment: For the case problem, see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400712/how-to-preserve-case-in-jsoup-parsing

Comment: As i mentioned in the description, i have already tried ParseSettings. It is not returning elements.

Comment: The hardest thing to do is to preserve case differences between tags of the same element, e.g. `<html> .. </HTML>`.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html#parseInput(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) is your friend… even when there is no description in that documentation.

Notice the first argument is named `html` and the second argument is named `baseUri`.

The first argument needs to be actual HTML content, not a filename.  Your code is trying to parse a filename as if it’s HTML.

The second argument needs to be a URI, or an empty string.  "UTF-8" is not a valid URI at all, though since you aren’t trying to resolve the links, it may not be a critical mistake.

You probably want [the Jsoup.parse method which takes both an InputStream and a customized Parser](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse(java.io.InputStream,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.jsoup.parser.Parser)):

```
Document doc;
try (InputStream content = new BufferedInputStream(
    new FileInputStream(input))) {

    doc = Jsoup.parse(content, null, "", parser);
}
```